# Jsonified Response from server

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I was trying to make a get request and obtain a jsonified response. But when i try this the request never gets completed. The browsers keeps on loading status only

```
@app.route('/user/json')
def json():
    users = User.query.all()
    list_serialized = [user.serialize() for user in users]
    return jsonify(list_serialized)


@app.route('/recieve')
def recieve():
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    users = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/json', headers=headers).json()
    print users
    return users
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you would have to make a `GET` request instead of directly calling the `json` function?

Comment: By default Flask only handles one request at a time, try `app.run(threaded=True)` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353192/flask-hangs-when-sending-a-post-request-to-itself)

Comment: check answer of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979817/why-python-requests-library-failing-to-get-response

Answer (score -1):

use `app.run(threaded=True)` for running app in `main` function.